# como puedo colocar el valor checked a un checkbox al hacer click en mi boton

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  mostrar2();
});

var mostrar2 = function() {
  var table = $("#tabla").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "conection.php"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "data": "product"
      },
      {
        "data": "category_id"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='editar btn btn-primary'>Editar</button><button type='button' class='eliminar btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEliminar' ><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>"
      }
    ]
  });
  obtener_data_editar("#tabla tbody", table);

}

var obtener_data_editar = function(tbody, table) {
  $(tbody).on("click", "button.editar", function() {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
    var Nombre = $("#id").val(data.name),
      Price = $("#nuevo").val(data.category_id);
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>formulario checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="producto">
    <tr>
      <td>

        <div><label>Seccion Nuevo:</label><input id="nuevo" type="checkbox" name="prodnuevo" value=""></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a que hacas el [tour] y también leas [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta, como tal tu pregunta es de baja calidad y no hay explicación alguna de lo que quieres lograr. Saludos

Comment: Cuál es el botón?

Comment: Hola les comento.!    mi boton es el que dice " obtener_data_editar ".  cuando yo doy click a mi boton me muestra la informacion en mi formulario pero tambien quiero que al mismo tiempo me haga un check en uno de los campos de mi formulario que tiene el id=nuevo.      disculpen si no me se explicar.!!! @Jorge Arturo Juarez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes marcar el check utilizando el atributo `.checked`. Este sería un ejemplo de su uso:

```js
function check() {
    $("#myCheck").prop('checked', true);
}

function uncheck() {
    $("#myCheck").prop('checked', false);
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<button onclick="check()">Check Checkbox</button>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck Checkbox</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: excelente me ha servido, es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

con jquery solamente usa .click() en tu checkbox

```js
  $('#validar').click(function() {
            $("#nuevo").click(); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Seccion Nuevo:</label><input id="nuevo" type="checkbox" name="prodnuevo" value=""></div>


<button id='validar'>check</button>
```